Vercel blob | Refresh | Download not working in production
I have created a Vercel Blob store and linked it to a Next JS project.
Once the upload or deletion happens. I am calling router.refresh() method. I am importing the method from next/navigation.
The upload | download | delete work fine and the list updates fine in local env.
But the same list doesn't update in production env and whilst downloading it gives 404 error - File wasn't available on site.
I have added files for both local and production envs with BLOB_READ_WRITE_TOKEN.
import { list } from "@vercel/blob";
const blobs = await list();
Please let me know if any more code or info is required.
Any views why this might be happening?
